# Android json error.index out of range

Tags: android

I am trying to get values from mysql and inserting them in sqlite database.But i am getting error in json index out of range.

**Here is my code**.
**I am getting json parsing Exception**:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) 
     {
        try{
            Database1 db=new Database1(getApplicationContext());

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i=0;i<=jArray.length();i++)
              {
                 JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    // list1.add(json_data.getString("id"));
                            int s=json_data.getInt("id");
                  j=json_data.getString("name");


              db.open();
              db.inserttable1(s,j);

                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),s+j,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  }
              }            
            catch(JSONException e)
             {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

Look here: `for(int i=0;i<=jArray.length();i++)`

The loop will still execute when `i=jArray.length()` which is once too often.

Change the loop to

```
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
```

Comment: If i will use this for loop i<jarray.lenght() i will only get one record from mysql databse.i want to get all records from mysql database

Comment: If you can show all values in Toast but only one gets inserted then something with your DB insertion code seems to be wrong.

Comment: i want to insert values in databse one by one.thats why i have used

Comment: Database1 db=new Database1(getApplicationContext());

Comment: db.open();
 db.inserttable1(s,j);inside for loop

Comment: Are you sure that the records have different id?

Comment: yes records have different ids.i am getting all records on php page

Comment: Try to move the `db.open()` out of the loop (i.e. do it only one time)

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop to below code

```
  for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
              {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                // list1.add(json_data.getString("id"));
                        int s=json_data.getInt("id");
              j=json_data.getString("name");


             db.open();
          db.inserttable1(s,j);

               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),s+j,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }
```

Comment: If i will use this for loop i<jarray.lenght() i will only get one record from mysql databse.i want to get all records from mysql database

Comment: and if i only show them in toast i am getting all values.but when i insert it in to sqlite databse.Only one value is being inserted

Comment: open the database outside the loop